# JSON. Денежные курсы

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть такой JSON ответ:

```
{
  "AUD": 44.95,
  "AZN": 33.73,
  "GBP": 73.42,
  "AMD": 0.12,
  "BYN": 30.96,
  "BGN": 32.01,
  "BRL": 18.8,
  "HUF": 0.2,
  "DKK": 8.42,
  "USD": 58.85,
  "EUR": 62.68,
  "INR": 0.88,
  "KZT": 0.18,
  "CAD": 44.74,
  "KGS": 0.85,
  "CNY": 8.55,
  "MDL": 2.94,
  "NOK": 7.02,
  "PLN": 14.55,
  "RON": 13.92,
  "ZZZ": 79.91,
  "SGD": 41.36,
  "TJS": 7.43,
  "TRY": 15.97,
  "TMT": 16.84,
  "UZS": 0.02,
  "UAH": 2.16,
  "CZK": 2.32,
  "SEK": 6.6,
  "CHF": 58.69,
  "ZAR": 4.4,
  "KRW": 0.05,
  "JPY": 0.52
}
```

Это курс рубля к другим валютам.

Функция должна принимать

1. сумма (amount)
2. конвертируемая валюта (from)
3. валюта для получения (to)

Я решил переводить from в рубли, затем эту сумму делить на рубли по курсу to. Можете ли предложить более совершенное решение? И я не могу никак подставить курс к переменной, в которой находиться распарсеные данные.

```js
function loadCurrencyJSON() {

return '{"AUD":44.95,"AZN":33.73,"GBP":73.42,"AMD":0.12,"BYN":30.96,"BGN":32.01,"BRL":18.8,"HUF":0.2,"DKK":8.42,"USD":58.85,"EUR":62.68,"INR":0.88,"KZT":0.18,"CAD":44.74,"KGS":0.85,"CNY":8.55,"MDL":2.94,"NOK":7.02,"PLN":14.55,"RON":13.92,"ZZZ":79.91,"SGD":41.36,"TJS":7.43,"TRY":15.97,"TMT":16.84,"UZS":0.02,"UAH":2.16,"CZK":2.32,"SEK":6.6,"CHF":58.69,"ZAR":4.4,"KRW":0.05,"JPY":0.52}';

}
// console.log(loadCurrencyJSON());

function convertCurrency(amount, from, to) {
  let val = loadCurrencyJSON();
  let parseVal = JSON.parse(val);
  let fromR = parseVal.from;
  let toR = parseVal.EUR;
  console.log(`${from} ${to}`);
  console.log(fromR);
  console.log(toR);
  
}

convertCurrency(300, 'USD', 'EUR');
```

Ссылка: https://repl.it/Jopt/2

Comment: Обновит код, чтобы в функции можно было вводить название валюты, и подогнал результат под ваш код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
var rates = {
  "AUD": 44.95,
  "AZN": 33.73,
  "GBP": 73.42,
  "AMD": 0.12,
  "BYN": 30.96,
  "BGN": 32.01,
  "BRL": 18.8,
  "HUF": 0.2,
  "DKK": 8.42,
  "USD": 58.85,
  "EUR": 62.68,
  "INR": 0.88,
  "KZT": 0.18,
  "CAD": 44.74,
  "KGS": 0.85,
  "CNY": 8.55,
  "MDL": 2.94,
  "NOK": 7.02,
  "PLN": 14.55,
  "RON": 13.92,
  "ZZZ": 79.91,
  "SGD": 41.36,
  "TJS": 7.43,
  "TRY": 15.97,
  "TMT": 16.84,
  "UZS": 0.02,
  "UAH": 2.16,
  "CZK": 2.32,
  "SEK": 6.6,
  "CHF": 58.69,
  "ZAR": 4.4,
  "KRW": 0.05,
  "JPY": 0.52
}

function getRate(amount, from, to) {
  return (amount * (rates[from] / rates[to])).toFixed(2);
}
console.log(getRate(100, 'KZT', 'EUR'));
```

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```js
function loadCurrencyJSON() {

  return '{"AUD":44.95,"AZN":33.73,"GBP":73.42,"AMD":0.12,"BYN":30.96,"BGN":32.01,"BRL":18.8,"HUF":0.2,"DKK":8.42,"USD":58.85,"EUR":62.68,"INR":0.88,"KZT":0.18,"CAD":44.74,"KGS":0.85,"CNY":8.55,"MDL":2.94,"NOK":7.02,"PLN":14.55,"RON":13.92,"ZZZ":79.91,"SGD":41.36,"TJS":7.43,"TRY":15.97,"TMT":16.84,"UZS":0.02,"UAH":2.16,"CZK":2.32,"SEK":6.6,"CHF":58.69,"ZAR":4.4,"KRW":0.05,"JPY":0.52}';

}
// console.log(loadCurrencyJSON());

function convertCurrency(amount, from, to) {
  let val = JSON.parse(loadCurrencyJSON());
  return (amount * (val[from] / val[to])).toFixed(2);

}

console.log(convertCurrency(300, 'USD', 'EUR'));
```